# Other acl manipulation executables than getfacl/setfacl?

Tags: acl

I am familiar with setfacl/getfacl. However, I am wondering if there are any other executables/packages that maintain similar functionality with regards to manipulating acl.

I am not looking for anything in particular, I am trying to contemplate the entire scope and logic of acl manipulation to get a complete picture of what is happening and what would be useful.

Examples of interesting behavior:

1. When a named group has been assigned, subsequent executions of chmod with regards to the owning group (ie chmod g+/-?) manipulate the acl's mask as opposed to the unnamed acl entry for the owning group. Perhaps this is a peculiarity of the setfacl/getfacl implementation and a different API provides different behavior.
2. Assignment of permissions cannot be done by appending permissions, eg: setfacl -m g:1:+rw.
3. Assignment cannot be done for all entities of a type, eg: setfacl -m g:*:perms

Comment: I can't wait till the behavior is changed from needing a mere 5 users to waste peoples time by closing valuable questions.

Comment: This is multiple questions in one.  For the _one question per question_ approach, see the likes of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475698/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347836/ .

Answer (score 1):

If you export the file system with Samba you can even use the native Windows tooling to manage the ACL's